# C# hashtable classes lookup by key is O(1)?

Tags: c#, hashtable, time-complexity

I read up on "Big O" and thought of the above. Is it correct ... ?

**Answer** (provided by @Mehrdad below): worst case is O(n)

Edit: sorry I meant 0(1), thanks @Coxy corrected that too.

Comment: Note that the type of complexity notation is just called "Big O" (rather than Big(o), as if 'Big' were a function.) Furthermore, the time complexity would be written as O(1) (...or O(n) or O(log n) depending), rather than log(1) which you have in the title.

Comment: you must know if you are looking for worst-case, or average-case complexity (or something else). They can be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it's O(1), or constant-time.

We say that the lookup is *on the order of `1`*, or, in math notation, `O(1)`. This means that, *in the worst case*, the lookup takes **constant** time*, irrespective of the data.

This is *amortized* worst-case time -- you might want to look this up, but basically, it means that, when spread out over the life of your hashtable, the cost is constant. *The actual worst-case time may be different than here, depending on how you make the buckets in the hashtable -- it can actually be anywhere from `O(1)` to `O(n)`, but the theoretical best is `O(1)` as I wrote here.*

Another note: I'm actually a bit sloppy with the notation myself: to *really* do it correctly [requires set notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations).

Comment: It's not *worst case* O(1). A hash table consisting entirely of keys which have the same hash code is O(n). It's O(1) in the usual case of no or few hash collisions. (At least assuming it's not using dynamic perfect hashing.)

Comment: @Jon: Isn't it amortized worst-case O(1) if you use certain techniques (like universal hashing) to make sure that it averages out in the end, even if certain collisions reduce to O(n) sometimes? And I thought Big-Oh was worst-case *by definition*... otherwise we'd use Theta instead of O, right?

Comment: @Mehrdad: thanks for pointing out I mean O(1) as in constant time.

Comment: @Merhdad: I'm not clear on the exact details of the differences between notation, but as an example quicksort is usually known as an O(n log n) algorithm but with a pathological worst case of O(n^2). As for the hash lookup... if you have n entries in a hash table using a single hash function, and that hash function returns the same value for all of those entries, then looking up every single entry is going to require O(n^2) equality comparisons (1+2+3+4+...n) so the average operation is O(n). Insertion is amortized to O(1) (in the usual case) because *almost all* insertion operations are O(1).

Comment: @Jon: I think you're assuming a chaining (or simple probing) implementation, right? While it's true that collisions reduce the worst case to `O(n)` for simple implementations, it doesn't have to be true for all hashtables. I made a little edit, hopefully that makes more sense?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Thanks for your input, why wouldn't a hashtable lookup always be approximately in constant time ? As you mention O(n) <- when would this happen ? thank you.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Thanks for input as well. "almost all insertion operations are O(1)" would you mind to elaborate just a few words when it's not the case? thank you.

Comment: @Sciphi: It's for the reason that Jon explained. To explain it a different way, a "hash" is like a "fingerprint". The more distinct people's fingerprints are, the easier you can identify them, and the easier it is to tell if someone is inside your table. But if lots of people happen to have similar fingerprints, then to tell find a person by his fingerprint you'd have to search *everybody* whose fingerprint looks like that person's (to do an exact comparison), and so that's `O(n)` time in the worst case. It doesn't happen often, but it can.

Comment: @Mehrdad: thanks for explaining further, but isn't the key of each hash value unique hence no duplicate finger prints exist in C#s implementation ?

Comment: @Sciphi: You don't have room to store all the keys inside a single slot (for a 32-bit integer, for example, that would require 4 GB of memory to *guarantee* no conflicts), so what you do is to put "similar" keys in the same slot (since you're not actually storing 4 billion integers), and hope that you don't get too many in the same slot. When you do, that's when bad things happen.

Comment: @Sciphi @Mehrdad: For insertions it's because the hash table has a fixed size of buffer at any one time; periodically it will need to grow, which involves copying everything you've already got. So even ignoring colllisions, you end up with operations of complexity 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 16, 1, 1, 1, 1, ... etc. (Roughly, depending on the exact implementation.) Even though there are occasional O(n) insertions - however good the hash is - this *averages* O(1) across all the insertions required to build a hash table of size n.

Comment: @Sciphi: Another way to look at the insertion issue is when you buy a computer for work: "I'll pay $1000 right now, *but the money I'll make with it will make up for the loss* in the future." (As if you're "borrowing" money, or in this case, time.) Same thing here.

Comment: "Bad things" don't happen when you have hash collisions, things just get slow.  GetHashCode is allowed to create values that collide, but it will degrade a lookup (in worst case) to traversing a list with the Equals operator.  Avoiding that is the whole point of a hash table/dictionary.  You only have a problem (incorrect behavior) when the Equals operator evaluates to true for objects with different hashes.  If this happens, it is a sign that you implemented Equals or GetHashCode wrong, and might break your lookups/inserts.